# Generate XML with 'SimpleXMLElement' with some empty filelds?

Tags: php, xml

```
$sitemap .= "  " . '<orders>' . "\n" .
    "\t" . '<idKlant>' . $id. '</idKlant>' .
    "\n\t" . '<emptyfield></emptyfield>' .
     "\n\t" . '<date>' . $verzenddatum . '</date>' . //remaining to get
    "\n  " . '</orders>' . "\n";
```

For generating XMl, I am using below code

```
$xmlobj = new SimpleXMLElement($sitemap);
$xmlobj->asXML("orders.xml");
```

Output of `orders.xml`

```
<orders>
    <idKlant>12</idKlant>
    <emptyfield/>
    <date>30-12-2012</date>
</orders>
```

What i want is: for Empty xml field there should be **Opening** and **Closing** tag as well

```
<orders>
    <idKlant>12</idKlant>
    <emptyfield></emptyfield>
    <date>30-12-2012</date>
</orders>
```

Is it possible? OR should i add black space?

Comment: Not with SimpleXMLElement, is DOMDocument an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

As Rolando Isidoro said you can't do it with SimpleXML. But you can always switch to the DOM. Both extension use the same underlying library and representation, so there is very little overhead.
[DOMDocument::saveXML](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) can take libxml options as the second parameter and there is [LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) which does exactly what you want.

e.g.

```
<?php
$o = new SimpleXMLELement(data());
$docRoot = dom_import_simplexml($o);
echo $docRoot->ownerDocument->savexml($docRoot,LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);

function data() {
    return '<orders>
    <idKlant>12</idKlant>
    <emptyfield/>
    <date>30-12-2012</date>
</orders>';
}
```

prints

```
<orders>
    <idKlant>12</idKlant>
    <emptyfield></emptyfield>
    <date>30-12-2012</date>
</orders>
```